# How can I extract points from JSON response of influxDB API?

Tags: python, json, influxdb, dataformat

I am using the python requests module to query the influxdb on my localhost using the influx API. The code is as follows.

```
import requests

INFLUX_DATABASE_NAME = "mydb"

influx_write_url = f'http://localhost:8086/write?db={INFLUX_DATABASE_NAME}'
influx_query_url = f'http://localhost:8086/query?db={INFLUX_DATABASE_NAME}'

pid = "CTR2257"
time_range = "7d"

pid_mod = "\'"+ pid +"\'"

query_string = f'SELECT "temp1"::field,"temp2"::field,"hum1"::field,"hum2"::field,"co2"::field,"light"::field,"fan"::field FROM "stat" WHERE productID = {pid_mod} AND time > now() - {time_range}'

payload = {'q': query_string}
r = requests.get(url=influx_query_url, params=payload)

# Printing the response content(JSON data)
print(r.content)
```

The print statement produces the below output. The output contains the desired dataset but the formatting is not preferred.

```
b'{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"series":[{"name":"stat","columns":["time","temp1","temp2","hum1","hum2","co2","light","fan"],"values":[["2020-11-04T22:09:26.4960419Z",32,34,65,68,9,true,true],["2020-11-04T23:31:33.8177588Z",30,32,90,85,5,true,true],["2020-11-04T23:31:46.5988965Z",30,32,90,85,5,true,true],["2020-11-04T23:31:49.9271554Z",30,32,90,85,5,true,true]]}]}]}\n'
```

When I parse this data using .json() method from requests module

```
request_data = r.json()
print(request_data)
```

I get the below python dictionary. Again the formatting is same and is not desired.

```
{'results': [{'statement_id': 0, 'series': [{'name': 'stat', 'columns': ['time', 'temp1', 'temp2', 'hum1', 'hum2', 'co2', 'light', 'fan'], 'values': [['2020-11-04T22:09:26.4960419Z', 32, 34, 65, 68, 9, True, True], ['2020-11-04T23:31:33.8177588Z', 30, 32, 90, 85, 5, True, True], ['2020-11-04T23:31:46.5988965Z', 30, 32, 90, 85, 5, True, True], ['2020-11-04T23:31:49.9271554Z', 30, 32, 90, 85, 5, True, True]]}]}]}
```

What I am looking for is to get the point data for each field in long format instead of wide format. For ex.

```
temp1 = [point1, point2, point3,....pointn]
temp2 = [point1, point2, point3,....pointn]
hum1 = [point1, point2, point3,....pointn]
hum2 = [point1, point2, point3,....pointn]

and so own.
```

Any ideas or help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using the official influxdb python library? It is very convenient to use because you can output a pandas dataframe or a results set. https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python

Comment: Yes, that's what I have been using since and successfully implemented it. But I was curious about converting the wide data to a long format and it didn't click me, I am sure that it can be done using the Python map function.